Issue with Google Sign-in Implementation in React Native App (Avoiding Firebase)
I'm encountering difficulties implementing Google sign-in functionality in my React Native application. Despite setting up the necessary credentials on the Google Cloud Console and ensuring the correct SHA1 for the Android client ID, I'm facing challenges.
Here's the scenario:
Configuration Issue: When I include the webClientId in the GoogleSignin configuration, I encounter a "DEVELOPER_ERROR" after signing in.
Null idToken: However, if I omit the webClientId, the sign-in process works, but the idToken returned from userInfo is null.

Here's an overview of my implementation:
I'm using React Native without Expo.
I've set up the necessary client IDs on the Google Cloud Console.
I've ensured that the SHA1 for the Android client ID is correct.
The sign-in process works when I omit the webClientId, but the idToken is null.
When I include the webClientId, I encounter a "DEVELOPER_ERROR" after signing in.

Additionally, I want to mention that I prefer not to use Firebase for authentication since I'm already using MongoDB for storing my data and handling the sign-up/sign-in process with email.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

function SigninChoiceScreen({ route }) {

  const { setIsLoggedIn } = route.params;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: process.env.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
      androidClientId: process.env.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
      iosClientId: process.env.IOS_CLIENT_ID,
      scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    });
  }, []);

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const idToken = userInfo.idToken; 

      if (idToken) {
        // Enregistrez le token Google dans AsyncStorage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('googleToken', idToken);

        // Définissez l'état isLoggedIn à true
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', JSON.stringify(true));
      } else {
        console.log('Google idToken is null');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('User Cancelled the Login Flow');
      } else if (error === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Signin in');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('Play Services not available');
      } else {
        console.log('some other error happened');
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Sign In</Text>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/logo_em.png')} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.choicesContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.choiceButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signin")}>
          <Text style={styles.choiceButtonText}>Sign In with Email</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.choiceButton} onPress={signIn}>
          <Text style={styles.choiceButtonText}>Sign in with Google</Text> 
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.choiceButton2} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signup")}>
          <Text style={styles.choiceButtonText2}>Sign Up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 150,
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  logoContainer: {},
  logo: {
    width: 250,
    height: 50,
  },
  choicesContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  choiceButton: {
    width: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  choiceButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  choiceButton2: {
    width: '30%',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  choiceButtonText2: {
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default SigninChoiceScreen;

Here is my configuration:


{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "set NODE_ENV=.env.development && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.8.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.30.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "realm": "^12.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-dotenv": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}




You should probably request the openid scope.
 ...
 useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      ...
      scopes: ['profile', 'email', 'openid'],
    });
  }, []);
  ...

The idToken is a concept coming from openID specification. Therefore, it is usually delivered only when it is requested.
You can find more information about open-ID support and "Google Sign-In" here : https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#sendauthrequest

Thanks for your answer, I tried that but nothing changed, still having idToken null when i don't put webClientId in the GoogleSignin.configure object, and when i put still have DEVELOPER_ERROR

create the consent screen OAUTH, fill the form like this
name  = whatever you want
email = your email
developter email = your developer email

add permissions(click and choose) in order to enable the following scopes: ['profile', 'email', 'openid'],
create credentials in console
for the package name you shoud to get from build.gradle in this line namespace "com.two"
Go to the /android/app located in your project and execute this code: keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
you should to set up firebase in index.js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';


import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "A...x-_3X..._S-F...k4",
    authDomain: "baserbase-e...824e.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "baserbase-e...824e",
    storageBucket: "baserbase-e...824e.appspot.com",
    databaseURL: "https://baserbase-e...824e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    messagingSenderId: "14...627", //i got this from cloud messaging section
    appId: "1:1...9627:android:2d...6ee", // sdk section
  };

if (!firebase?.apps?.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

and now you can use this template:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const LoginScreen = ({ handleLogin }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // get webClientId from credentials, web credentials works as well for android project
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: '17...27-u...lu.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    });
  }, []);

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      handleLogin(true);
      
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('Inicio de sesión cancelado');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Inicio de sesión en progreso');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('Google Play Services no están disponibles');
      } else {
        console.log('Error al iniciar sesión con Google:', error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.logo}>betplus</Text>
      <GoogleSigninButton
        style={styles.googleButton}
        size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
        color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
        onPress={signIn}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  logo: {
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  googleButton: {
    width: 312,
    height: 48,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;

now you can go the authentication from firebase to see who logged in your app

Follow these instructions
Get the right sha1 key match details
Variant: debugAndroidTest 
Config: debug 
Store: /Users/..../..../.../android/app/debug.keystore 
Alias: androiddebugkey MD5: 65:01:AE:C5:89:21:98:57:CB:D9:17:76:55:52:34:4F SHA1: FA:D4:3F:12:DF:F4:DA:B0:04:41:1A:49:E8:DB:A3:91:AE:FC:D0:9C SHA-256: 8A:36:45:A1:CA:21:4C:7F:35:1F:32:66:1B:64:FA:06:7C:FB:3C:0B:FB:57:3D:19:17:BC:6E:55:5F:C4:FD:ED


Create an android client id with package and sha1 key. In the 'advanced settings' verify the owner and enable checkbox : Custom URI scheme
Generate a web client id without any redirect url
On the consent screen tab, add permissions in scope : Oauth
./auth/userinfo.email
./auth/userinfo.profile
openid

And in scope, also add 'Test users' with your mail which will be verified in google sign in button
You will now be able to copy the web client id and use it in your code.
